# Resizable UIWebView/WKWebView contentView in UITablewViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwebview, key-value-observing

I have UIWebView in UITableViewCell (url for ex.: http://advisa.work/bank_partner/webview01.html , it has resizable content height).
So I observe it contentSize

```
func startObservingHeight() {
   let options = NSKeyValueObservingOptions([.new])
   webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "scrollView.contentSize", options: options, context: nil)
}
```

So code below is called only when contentSize of webView is growing. So I increase my tableViewCell, and when I shrink some parts of html document (css changes), function below not calling, and I cannot resize cell.

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {        
  if let zeChange = change as? [NSKeyValueChangeKey: NSValue] {
    let newSize = zeChange[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey]?.cgSizeValue
    changeHeight?(newSize.height)
  }
}
```

this my callback variable:

```
var changeHeight: ((CGFloat?) -> ())?
```